# Kotlinx serialisation, common interface or type class

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I am working on a plugin type system where 3rd parties will register classes that will expose data. I don't know exactly what the data will look like but I will enumerate these plugin instances collect the data and I would like to serialise it. A simplified version.

```
interface DataProvider {
  fun getDataThatIsSerializable() : ???
}
```

What can i set the return type to so that I know that I will be able to serialise it with kotlinx serialisation. I cannot see any common interface that is injected into the class and given thet kotlin doesn't support type classes its not clear how to achieve what I am trying to do?

I considered something like this:

```
interface DataProvider {
  fun getDataThatIsSerializable() : Pair<Any,KSerializer<*>>
}
```

but i could not pass this into the Json.encodeAsString functions, the types do not match

Are there any other options I can consider?

Comment: Hi Luke, can you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This would make it much more easy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

`kotlinx.serialization` doesn't like serializing things unless you can tell it exactly what you're working with.

Would it make sense for the DataProvider to be responsible for serializing its own data? Something like:

```kotlin
interface DataProvider {
    fun getDataThatIsSerializable() : Any
    fun encodeAsJsonString(data: Any) : String
}

@Serializable
data class Foo(val value: Int)

class FooDataProvider : DataProvider {
    override fun getDataThatIsSerializable() : Any {
        return Foo(7)
    }

    override fun encodeAsJsonString(data: Any): String {
        return Json.encodeToString(Foo.serializer(), data as Foo)
    }
}
```